# Can I transpile `fnname = _ => {}` into `function fnname(){}`?

Tags: javascript

I have top-level functions like this:

```
fnname = _ => {
}
```

But I need to convert them into:

```
function fnname() {
}
```

So that my minifier/parser/etc can mangle the names.

Is this possible using an automated tool?

---

Babel set to 2015 with all the transformations forced doesn't work.

It turns

```
fnname = _ => { 
  return "hi" 
}
```

into

```
fnname = function fnname(_) { 
  return "hi"; 
};
```

Note: it's not `function fnname()...` as desired.

See: [Babel online here](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?browsers=defaults%2C%20not%20ie%2011%2C%20not%20ie_mob%2011&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=IYAgvCD64Hwg3gKBCATgUwC4FdUDsQAiACwEtDEBfIA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=true&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=false&presets=env%2Ces2015%2Cenv&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.10.4&externalPlugins=)

Comment: Lambda functions in JavaScript inherit `this` from their parent, but functions do not. So the rewritten code you're proposing would not always be equivalent. Unless you call `.bind(this)` on the resulting function.

Comment: No. You cant. Arrow functions and normal functions are not equivalent so something that turns arrow functions into normal functions isnt transpilation, it's just an arbitrary replacement with no guarantee of functioning equivalently to the original code

Answer (score -1):

You can use a transpiler like [babel](https://babeljs.io/) in order to automate it for you. Just target `es2015` or force all transformations.

Comment: Please see updated question. Babel doesn't make it `function fnname()`.

Comment: @newfivefour There's no difference between `function fnname()` and `fnname = function fnname()`, right? Both give you a named function in the same scope.

Comment: @ATOMP There's a difference because 'parser' doesn't mangle the latter

Comment: if you just want to transform from `fname = function fname()` into `function fname()`...a simple regex would work.

Comment: Thanks. That's probably the best idea so far. I don't suspect manglers will transform it as I want because the former is technically a dictionary name on the window object, and dictionary names are generally not mangled by manglers, from what I understand.